# Checking against user input and returns a response based on that input

Tags: rust

How could I use enums in the following block of code to simplify it? The block is a program that has a command interpreter that returns different data based on user input. Is there a way I could easily apply enums and a match statement to the logic here?

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let version = String::from("0.0.1");
    let mut input = String::new();

    shell(&mut input, &version);
}

fn shell(input: &mut String, version: &String) {
    input.clear();
    match io::stdin().read_line(input) {
        Ok(b) => {
            if &input.trim() == &"ver" || &input.trim() == &"what are you" {
                println!("C ute R ust A mateur B eginner Shell ver: {}", version);
                shell(input, version);
            } else {
                println!("Command '{}' Not Recognized", input);
                shell(input, &version);
            }
        }
        Err(err) => panic!("incorrect"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). I know the code you've presented is formatted correctly now, but that's because I reformatted it for you over on Stack Overflow (I wouldn't have touched it here).
2. Read and address the compiler's warning messages!

   ```
   warning: unused variable: `b`
     --> src/main.rs:13:12
      |
   13 |         Ok(b) => {
      |            ^ help: consider using `_b` instead
      |
      = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default

   warning: unused variable: `err`
     --> src/main.rs:22:13
      |
   22 |         Err(err) => panic!("incorrect"),
      |             ^^^ help: consider using `_err` instead

   warning: function cannot return without recursing
     --> src/main.rs:10:1
      |
   10 | fn shell(input: &mut String, version: &String) {
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot return without recursing
   ...
   16 |                 shell(input, version);
      |                 --------------------- recursive call site
   ...
   19 |                 shell(input, &version);
      |                 ---------------------- recursive call site
      |
      = note: #[warn(unconditional_recursion)] on by default
      = help: a `loop` may express intention better if this is on purpose

       Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.16s
        Running `target/debug/playground`
   ```
3. Don't have infinite recursion; that's almost always a bad idea and you will run out of stack space. Write an infinite loop instead.
4. There's no reason to put `input` outside of the function, as it's only ever used inside it.
5. Use [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy). It will point out things like:

   ```
   warning: writing `&String` instead of `&str` involves a new object where a slice will do.
    --> src/main.rs:9:19
     |
   9 | fn shell(version: &String) {
     |                   ^^^^^^^ help: change this to: `&str`
     |
     = note: #[warn(clippy::ptr_arg)] on by default
     = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#ptr_arg

   warning: needlessly taken reference of both operands
     --> src/main.rs:15:16
      |
   15 |             if &input.trim() == &"ver" || &input.trim() == &"what are you" {
      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: #[warn(clippy::op_ref)] on by default
      = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#op_ref
   help: use the values directly
      |
   15 |             if input.trim() == "ver" || &input.trim() == &"what are you" {
      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^
   ```

   See also:

   - [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)
6. Use `Result::expect` instead of doing the `match` yourself. This has the beenfit of printing out the underlying error message as well.
7. Store the result of `trim` to avoid doing the work multiple times.
8. Consider using a `match` on the trimmed string to decide what to work on.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let version = "0.0.1";

    shell(version);
}

fn shell(version: &str) {
    let mut input = String::new();
    loop {
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("incorrect");
        let input = input.trim();

        match input {
            "ver" | "what are you" => {
                println!("C ute R ust A mateur B eginner Shell ver: {}", version)
            }
            _ => println!("Command '{}' Not Recognized", input),
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can consider how best to use enums here. An enum is good for a type that can be one of many values. You have that structure in your "command" decisions. You could create an enum from those strings:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let version = "0.0.1";

    shell(version);
}

fn shell(version: &str) {
    let mut input = String::new();
    loop {
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("incorrect");
        let command = input.trim().parse::<Command>();

        use Command::*;
        match command {
            Ok(Version) | Ok(WhatAreYou) => {
                println!("C ute R ust A mateur B eginner Shell ver: {}", version)
            }
            Err(_) => println!("Command '{}' Not Recognized", input),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Command {
    Version,
    WhatAreYou,
}

impl std::str::FromStr for Command {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(input: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        use Command::*;
        Ok(match input {
            "ver" => Version,
            "what are you" => WhatAreYou,
            _ => return Err(()),
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: All of your notes are extremely helpful. I think it's really interesting how you added the FromStr trait to the Command enum for parsing the input string into a string. I've used your notes to modify the project I'm currently working on which is a blackjack game in rust. Thank you so much. Here's the blackjack game just in case you'd like to look over that too: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d28be92bd21393a465186577ead00979